# AIX JDK 1.8 download

Tags: java, aix

I need to get an archive containing AIX JDK 1.8 that doesnt need anything else. Just unpack and execute java binary. The dowload from IBM is labeled "non-install", but in fact it needs precompiled jre allready in place to run the installation procedure. I need only tar or zip that I can unpack and go.

I have tried searching SO, google...but to no avail.

Comment: Exactly what file did you download? Exactly how did you try to to install it? Exactly what error message did you get?

Answer (score 0):

You should get two files sg like these:

```
-rw------- 1 projects system 181881856 Dec  4 10:28 Java8_64.jre
-rw------- 1 projects system  16879616 Dec  4 10:22 Java8_64.sdk
```

These files are meant to be installed with program 'installp':

```
# installp -aY -d. Java8_64.jre Java8_64.sdk
```

Comment: @OP Though It is not clear that you want JRE without JDK, or JDK without JRE, or don't know the difference.